# C# Dictionary giving a KeyNotFoundException, not sure why

Tags: c#, dictionary, keynotfoundexception

I'm an amateur programmer, and this seems like a simple problem to fix, but I just can't figure out how.
Below is C# code that isn't acting like I want it to. I expect for this to return 3, yet instead throws a `KeyNotFoundException`. The Lists are the same, so shouldn't it be returning 3? Thanks for any help.

```
Dictionary<object, double> dict = new Dictionary<object, double>();
dict.Add(new List<object>() { "a", "b" }, 3);
double output = dict[new List<object>() { "a", "b" }];
```

Comment: Using a List<> object as the key of a Dictionary is not a good idea, it goes against most general use cases.

Comment: What would be a better replacement? If I have a list of objects, but I don't know how many objects there are or what type they are, how do I map these to numbers?

Comment: well @Daniel Hilgarth provided you with a decent alternative `Tuple`, but to give a more specific answer you would have to give examples of the type of objects you need to put into the dictionary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`List<T>` is a reference type without a special `Equals` implementation. So, in your case, while both of your list instances have the same content, they are still *different* instances and as such are not considered equal upon key lookup.

Depending on your needs, you could use different solutions:

1. If you always have the same amount of items in your list, you can use a Tuple:

   ```
   Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, double> dict =
       new Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, double>();
   dict.Add(Tuple.Create("a", "b"), 3);
   double output = dict[Tuple.Create("a", "b")];
   ```
2. If the amount of items differ, you can create your own list that compares its content.

Comment: Thanks. Is this because of how some objects (like lists) are stored by reference, while others are not?

Comment: @vlts: This is a rather broad topic, but in short: In .NET there are value types and reference types. Value types are compared by content, reference types are - by default - compared by reference, i.e. two different instances with the same data are *not* considered equal. However, you can override this behavior by overriding `object.Equals` in your class.

Answer (score 1):

Because there are two different objects/instances.

Answer (score 1):

Both lists are separate instances, so [`ReferenceEquals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals.aspx) returns `false`, but that is used by default. You could implement a custom `IEqualityComparer<IList<object>>` for the dictionary constructor:

```
public class ListComparer : IEqualityComparer<IList<object>>
{
    public bool Equals(IList<object> x, IList<object> y)
    {
        if (x == null || y == null) return false;
        return x.SequenceEqual(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IList<object> list)
    {
        if (list == null) return int.MinValue;
        int hash = 19;
        unchecked // Overflow is fine, just wrap
        {
            foreach (object obj in list)
                if(obj != null)
                    hash = hash + obj.GetHashCode();
        }
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Now it works as expected:

```
var  dict = new Dictionary<List<object>, double>(new ListComparer());
dict.Add(new List<object>() { "a", "b" }, 3);
double output = dict[new List<object>() { "a", "b" }]; // 3.0
```